# glVertexPointer get error with GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: opengl-es

I am newbie for OPENGLES. I have a problem that boring all day. I just want to draw a triangle on the screen, but I failed. I always get an error when using

```
GLfloat vertices[] = 
{
    0, 0,0, 
    100,0,0,
     0,100,0
}; 
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);//always get GL_INVALID_ENUM error
```

I have checked the doc and it said that GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if type is not an accepted value.But I set the type as GL_FLOAT, Why is it unsupported?It will get running error "Unhandled exception at 0x691e1df0 in OglesExercise.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." in glDrawArrays method If the program continues to run with GL_INVALID_ENUM.
what's more, when I changed the type of vertices to GLfixed, and using

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FIXED, 0, vertices);
```

There is no error occur, but the screen shows nothing, the triangle will not appear on the screen.
Is anyone can help me to solve this problem? Is this problem related to platform? I'm using Windows XP and the CPU is AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5600+.

Comment: who can help me ....so boring....

Comment: Is there any requirement of the vs 2008 project settings for this opengl es programming?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are supplying the wrong number of parameters to `glVertexAttribPointer`. It takes six parameters. Your method invocation only passes four.

If you check the [OpenGL-ES docs on glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml), you can find the API specification:

```
void glVertexAttribPointer( GLuint index,
                            GLint size,
                            GLenum type,
                            GLboolean normalized,
                            GLsizei stride,
                            const GLvoid * pointer);
```